# SQL trigger inside if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.
>
> Msg 140, Level 15, State 1, Line 44
> Can only use IF UPDATE within a CREATE TRIGGER statement.

I don't understand what I'm doing wring here the code creating a trigger runs fine outside of the IF statement but as soon as I put it inside the statement I cant run it. is there some syntax that I'm messing up or something along those lines? when i hover over the columns i get a message that reads an invalid column name which doesn't make sense to me because I had this code running fine without the IF statement.

[image]

```
USE [Elearn2]
GO

IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'AspNetUserEmailAudit') 
                  AND type IN (N'U'))
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit]
    (
        [AuditId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [AuditDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
        [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
        [NormalizedEmail] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
        [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

        CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserEmailAudit] 
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AuditId] ASC)
                        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit] 
        ADD DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [AuditId]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit] 
        ADD DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [AuditDate]
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE name = 'MyTrigger')
BEGIN
    CREATE TRIGGER AspNetUsersEmail_trigger
    ON AspNetUsers
    AFTER UPDATE 
    AS
        ****Error starts***
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        IF (UPDATE(Email))
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit]
                   (UserId, UserName, Email, NormalizedEmail, FirstName, LastName)
                SELECT Id, UserName, Email, NormalizedEmail, FirstName, LastName
                FROM inserted i
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT i.Id, i.Email   
                              EXCEPT
                              SELECT d.Id, d.Email
                              FROM deleted d);
    *****
END
GO  

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[AspNetRoles] 
               WHERE [NormalizedName] = 'SUPERADMIN')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id], [Name], [NormalizedName], [ConcurrencyStamp])
    VALUES (NEWID(), 'SuperAdmin', 'SUPERADMIN', NULL)  
END

DECLARE @userrole nvarchar(256)

SET @userrole = (SELECT [RoleId] 
                 FROM [Elearn2].[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] 
                 WHERE [UserId] = 'E96380FB-1823-453C-9436-08D92532AE7D')

PRINT @userrole

DECLARE @user nvarchar(256)

SET @user = (SELECT [Id] FROM [Elearn2].[dbo].[AspNetUsers] 
             WHERE [UserName] = 'super')
PRINT @user

UPDATE [Elearn2].[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
SET [RoleId] = @userrole
WHERE [UserId] = @user
```

Comment: Per the [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql#trigger-limitations), "`CREATE TRIGGER` must be the first statement in the batch". You cannot do `IF NOT EXISTS ... CREATE TRIGGER` unless you wrap the whole trigger creation in an `EXEC`.

Comment: Place the whole `CREATE TRIGGER` statement in a `EXECUTE sp_executesql N'<your create trigger statement here>'`.

Comment: @TT I still get the errors when I through it inside an EXECUTE

Comment: @JeroenMostert could i put it inside an IF EXISTS? or is that just the same problem? I tried the EXEC and it seems to through the same errors

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sorry, I was using the wrong syntax now its working

Comment: You might want to look at `CREATE OR ALTER`